# Qt "tcpserver->write(string)"

Tags: c++, string, qt, tcp, send

i have a very simple question here, How can i send a string with

```
tcpserver->write(string);
```

I tried:

```
tcpserver->write("string")
```

and it works, but if i want to input a string in there, i get a "no matching function to call to 'QtcpSocket::write(QString)'"
error,

so i tried converting the string to "data" and then send it, but i got a ton of errors...

And my question is: How can i easly send a string thru my tcpserver?

(I should also mention, that i am very new to programming)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert string to QByteArray, for example:

tcpserver->write(string.toLocal8Bit());

Answer (score 1):

```
tcpserver->write(string.toUtf8());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try tcpserver->write((const char *)string.data(), string.length()*sizeof(QChar));

Answer (score 0):

QTcpSocket has 3 overloads for write () function

```
qint64 write (const char *data);
qint64 write (const char *data, qint64 len);
qint64 write (const QByteArray &data);
```

So Convert QString to any of them. Just try

```
tcpserver->write (string.toLatin1 ());
```